# magento 1.9.2.0 Invalid login alert message displayed twice. on internet explorer 11

Tags: magento-1.9.2.0

[image: magento 1.9.2.0 Invalid login alert message displayed twice. on internet explorer 11]

magento 1.9.2.0 Invalid login alert message displayed twice. on internet explorer 11

Answer (score 0):

Make sure cookies/caches are cleared, and also make sure the form key is being loaded into the login template.

If there are no customizations to the admin login, then your template should be:

`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/login.phtml`

This input should be inside the `<form>` element:

`<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $this->getFormKey() ?>" />`

Comment: it is not work. please update any ideas.